# loading a page outside of its folder (ajax)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, file

I am trying to load this file which located in another folder outside of its current folder.

More precisely, this file is located in

```
root/js/search.js


 $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#results").load("../functions/populateResults.php");  //initial page number to load
      $(".pagination").bootpag({
         total: <?php echo $pages; ?>,
         page: 1,
         maxVisible: 5
      }).on("page", function(e, num){
        e.preventDefault();
        window.scrollTo(0, 0);

        $("#results").prepend('<div class="loading-indication"><img src="ajax-loader.gif" /> &nbsp; Please wait... Loading New Courses...</div>');
        $("#results").load("../functions/populateResults.php", {'page':num});
      });

    });
```

and I am trying to get to load a file located in `root/functions/populateResults.php`, my attempt have seen above does not seem to work and would kindly appreciate some assistance.

All the best,
Jonathan Etienne

Comment: where your js file is located isn't relevant... what matters is where the page it is used in is located

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not use relative urls for ajax.

Either they have to be

```
$("#results").load("/functions/populateResults.php");
```

Or you should use the full path

```
$("#results").load("http://yoursite.com/functions/populateResults.php");
```

Comment: first statement is not true ... and you can also use `/functions/populateResults.php` without domain and protocol ... the leading `/` will start at root

Comment: Ahh... yes. As long as it is not relative.

Comment: and you certainly can use relative url's

Comment: thank you i tried $("#results").load("/functions/populateResults.php");
 but unfortunatetly it does not seem the file

Comment: i am using localhost so the url is http://localhost:8080/websitename/searchpage.php  so i think with /functions/populateResults.php it starts from localhost:8080/ and not from the website name

Comment: If you are using a php framework there will be a variable that holds that "root" part of your URL. If you are rolling your own code, I would recommend making such a variable.